# How to avoid the GUI password prompt when using `osascript`?

Tags: password, sudo, applescript

I’d like to use the `osascript` shell command to run some AppleScript, but I’d rather avoid the GUI password prompt. Instead, I’d prefer to run the script as `sudo` from the command-line, so no GUI popups/prompts are needed.

The command is the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true'
```

Running this command has the same effect as going to *System Preferences* → *Accessibility* and checking *Enable access for assistive devices*.

If it doesn’t prompt for your password, try the opposite:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to false'
```

For either one of these commands you’ll get a password prompt in the OS X GUI:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: **is there any way to avoid this password prompt?**

---

I assumed invoking `osascript` with `sudo` privileges would do the trick, but alas — even in that case the GUI prompt is shown. :(

```
sudo osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true'
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't know if was just an example, but you can also enable access for assistive devices with `sudo touch /var/db/.AccessibilityAPIEnabled`.

Comment: @Lri `echo -n 'a' | sudo tee /private/var/db/.AccessibilityAPIEnabled > /dev/null 2>&1; sudo chmod 444 /private/var/db/.AccessibilityAPIEnabled` ([as used here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/commit/b9fa939cefe4f76336ce12ab83108c4e1d00e242)) more closely mimics what enabling the setting in System Preferences does, although it’s not instant (unlike going through SysPrefs manually). Any idea on which service to restart after this command? Anyhow, as you guessed, it was just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress the password interface by modifying your Mac's [authorization rights](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/).

Use the built-in [security](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/security.html) command line tool or [authbuddy](http://www.dssw.co.uk/authbuddy/) to change the `system.preferences.accessibility` right to `allow`:

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.preferences.accessibility allow
```

Opening up the [system.preferences.accessibility](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/system-preferences-accessibility.html) right will permit any user to change the accessibility settings without a password prompt.

Comment: Very cool trick — thanks! Unfortunately this poses a potential security risk, as now any apps could make such changes as well.

Comment: Only authenticated administrators may alter authorization rights. `allow` is one of many possible rules to test against and other rules are available to choose from or to create. The security manual page shows how to apply alternatives.

Comment: Yes, only authenticated administrators can run the above script (`sudo`) — but I meant that after that, all apps on the system are able to change accessibility settings at will.

Comment: how do we reverse this process?

Comment: @ikel Please could you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Comments are less visible on this site and a new question will better attract answers. Feel free to mention this question and answer in the new question.

Comment: @ikel the [referenced docs](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/security.html) indicate `authorizationdb` takes the following format: `authorizationdb write <right-name> [allow|deny|<rulename>]`. so it would be as simple as changing the `allow` parameter to `deny` as in: `sudo security authorizationdb write system.preferences.accessibility deny`.

Comment: If the rule is set to `deny`, no-one – including administrators – will be able to access the `system.preferences.accessibility` controlled settings.